# Open Excel file and format for import to Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to prep an Excel file for import.
I used the macro recorder to get the code to remove the header and shift the rows up for my column headers for my temp table in Access.

I am trying to find a specific value in a column, then delete everything below it.

```vb
Public Function FormatSPExcel()

    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strfile As String
    Dim r As Range ' range variable
    Dim d As String ' rows to delete variable

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3)
    
    With fd
        .allowmultiselect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls*"
        If .Show Then
            strfile = .selecteditems(1)
        End If
    End With
        
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(strfile)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet0")
    
    'deletes and cleans up header
    ws.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Rows("1:21").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                
    'delete footer up to and including total
    Set r = ws.Range("A:K").Find("Total", lookin:=xlValues)
    
    Do While Not r Is Nothing
        d = "A:K" & r.Row + 30
        ws.Range(d).Delete xlShiftUp
        Set r = ws.Range("A:K").Find("Total", lookin:=xlValues)
    Loop
                
    wb.Save
    xl.Quit
    Set xl = Nothing
            
End Function
```

This fails at `ActiveSheet.Range(d).Delete xlShiftUp` and says

> Application-defined or object-defined error

I cobbled this together from various things across StackOverflow and other sites. It is finding the row but I think I did the delete part wrong.

I want to find the row with a specific value, in this case "Total" then store as string to delete that row and a large chunk of rows below it.

Comment: You need a number after "A" in the range.

Comment: Don't use global Excel objects like Selection or ActiveSheet. Only fully qualified local variables like ws. Otherwise your code will only work once. -- Avoid using .Select at all.

Answer (score 0):

When you are programming in Excel and write `ActiveSheet`, the VBA compile will silently translate this into `Application.ActiveSheet`. Similar, `Workbooks` is translated to `Application.Workbooks` , and this is done for a lot of other members of the `Application`-object.

When you are programming in Access, there is also an `Application`-object, but this time it's an *Access* Application that has different members, the `CurrentDb` is one of them.

If you are in Access and want to use the members of the `Excel.Application` object, simply use your Excel application object (you named it `xl` in your function), so write for example `xl.ActiveSheet`.

However, is your case it's even not neccessary to use ActiveSheet at all as you have the worksheet assigned to a variable (`ws`). It's much better to write `ws.Range(d).Delete xlShiftUp`.

Comment: Maybe include the fact that `d = "A:K" & r.Row + 30` doesn't produce a valid range reference too?

Comment: I just ran it again making the change to ws, but you are correct. in that its not producing a valid range. Now I just need to figure out what I did incorrectly in that.

Comment: Yes, and there are other issues, eg. using `rows` instead of `ws.rows`. @Timyers: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1

Comment: The delete header part I just used the macro recorder. I should probably clean it up though.